# Pass a value in modal to delete record

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to make a modal for delete confirmation, but I can't take the value of the record from the table and pass it to the modal and delete the record.

```
$query1=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tab1 where username = '$row[username]'");

 while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
 {
  echo '  
        <tr class ="item" id=echo $row["country"]">    
        <td>'.$row["country"].'</td>  
        <td>
        <a class="Danger danger-color" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DangerModalalert"> 
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
        </td>



<div id="DangerModalalert" class="modal modal-edu-general FullColor-popup-DangerModal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-close-area modal-close-df">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash fa-2x"></span>
                <h2>Delete Confirmation</h2>
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete it?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer danger-md">
                <a data-dismiss="modal" href="#" style="background:red">No</a>
                <a href="#" style="background:red">Yes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Side note:_ Instead of echoing HTML using PHP like that, end the PHP block: `?>`, write your HTML and then open a PHP block again: `<?php`. Then IDE's can syntax highlight the HTML as well, which will make it _much_ easier to read and find potential issues.

Comment: This: `id=echo $row["country"]"` should be `id="' . $row["country"] . '"`. This is a good example for my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you only need one modal div. Add class `delete-yes` to delete button so we can replace it's href later from javascript

```html
<div id="DangerModalalert" class="modal modal-edu-general FullColor-popup-DangerModal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-close-area modal-close-df">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" href="#"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash fa-2x"></span>
                <h2>Delete Confirmation</h2>
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete it?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer danger-md">
                <a data-dismiss="modal" href="#" style="background:red">No</a>
                <a class="delete-yes" href="#" style="background:red">Yes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set url to delete link, and class `delete-confirm` for JS binding:

```
<a class="Danger danger-color delete-confirm" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DangerModalalert"> 
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
</a>
```

then add this JS code to bind delete button event

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete-confirm", function () {
     var deleteUrl = $(this).attr('href');
     $(".modal-body .delete-yes").attr('href', deleteUrl);
     return false;
});
```

Comment: So i don't need the "delete.php" file and i need a class "delete-yes"? i tried it but not works neither the with the "delete.php" ,neither with the class

Comment: You need both. The class is used to bind click event, and the `href="delete.php"` (you need to replace it with your delete URL) will be passed to modal's "Yes" button. What is the outcome when you tried it? Is there any javascript error? Is the page redirected to delete page?

Comment: <a class="Danger danger-color delete-confirm" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo '.$row["country"].';?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DangerModalalert"> 
......                                                                                                                      <a class="delete-yes" href="delete.php" id="delete" style="background:red">Yes</a>                                                                                is it like this? it is redirect but doing nothing ,it doesn't get the variable

Comment: My bad. In JS, replace attribute `url` with `href` : `$(".modal-body .delete-yes").attr('href', deleteUrl);`

Comment: Did it redirect to correct location? Have you created a delete file that reads country ID with `$_GET['id']`, and pass it to execute query `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE country_id = 'xxx'`?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$country =$_GET['country'];


mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM tab1 WHERE country = '$country'                     it is this one ,instead of id i have the country by its name

Comment: The request method is `GET`. So try to replace with `if(isset($_GET['country']))`. And I have to warn you, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please look up about prepared statement query

Comment: I think this is/was the best and most useful zero-upvotes answer I have ever seen on SO! It works very well, so please give Anggara an upvote if his work helps you.